# Spring, JPA, glassfish, EAR, TransactionRequiredException

Tags: spring, jpa, glassfish, ear

After nearly 10 hours of searching and trying different things I couldn't figure out, what is main cause of my problem. So, maybe someone could help me here. I'm learning Spring + JPA. I have EAR project (in Eclipse) consist of two projects: JPA and Servlets. This EAR is beeing deployed on Glassfish application server.

*JPA project:* Beans, Services and DAOs.

*Servlet project:* Only one simple HttpRequestHandlerServlet, calling service from JPA.

**Problem:** On servlet side, getting data from dao (through service) is working fine. Storing data is raising `TransactionRequiredException`.

---

## JPA project

### Dao:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public void persist(Employee entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

### Service:

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeDao dao;

public Employee store(Employee in) {
    dao.persist(in);
    return in;
}
```

### services.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:load-time-weaver />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/test" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testJPA" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="employeeDao" class="... EmployeeDaoImpl" />
<bean id="employeeService" class="... EmployeeServiceImpl">
    <property name="employeeDao" ref="employeeDao" />
</bean>
```

### beanRefContext.xml:

```
<bean id="serviceContext"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>classpath:services.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

### persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="testJPA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/test</jta-data-source> 
    <class>... entity.Employee</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    </properties> 
</persistence-unit>
```

---

## Servlet project

### web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>serviceContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="test" class="... TestServlet">
    <property name="employeeService" ref="employeeService" />
</bean>
```

---

## Summary

In test servlet, calling `employeeService.store( ... )` raises Exception:

```
    WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[test]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet testt threw exception
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper.throwCheckTransactionFailedException(JTATransactionWrapper.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper.checkForTransaction(JTATransactionWrapper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.checkForTransaction(EntityManagerImpl.java:1776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:780)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
```

### Main notes:

1. Problem is thrown by `em.flush()`.
2. Getting data from JPA / db is working well from servlets.
3. Out of container Unit tests in JPA project are working well (em.flush too).
4. Initialization of spring contexts seems to be fine according spring logs. ServiceContext is created and WebApplicationContext is created with its parrent afterwards.

I've tried to find problem somewhere in my hierarchical context initializing by placing  in Servlet project, I've also tried only one bean definition in servlet project's ApplicationContext.xml. None of that is working so problem will be probably somewhere else.

Really thanks for any comments, Regards Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched:

- glassfish -> jboss,
- eclipselink -> hibernate.

My configuration is working **without any** changes.

Comment: so glassfish is carp, ecliplink is equally carp?

Answer (score 1):

First off, consider that marking `@Transactional` directly on DAO level is design-wise considered somewhat ill-advised - usually, transactions span from service-layer, so putting transactional demarcation on service-layer only is recommended.

Secondly, though I haven't directly worked with EclipseLink JPA implementation, judging by this exception, you have tried to start a global transaction but you haven't configured a global (JTA) transaction manager implementation.

Your configuration also seems to hint at this:

- in services.xml, you have configured a locally-managed transaction manager (`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager`),
- in persistence.xml, you have configured JPA provider to expect GLOBAL transactions management for the given datasource (via `<jta-data-source>jdbc/test</jta-data-source>`)

If you need to work with local transactions (which is the case in 95% of situations), you must configure your JPA provider for LOCAL transaction with something like this:

```
    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
          <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/test</non-jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
```

If global transactions are what you indeed need, then you will need to inject a different transaction manager implementation into Spring context. More detailed instructions on how to configure this scenario depend on the actual implementation itself - two freely available that come to mind are [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com) and [Bitronix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Home). They both integrate with Spring quite well and are decently documented.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm sorry for being late (because of my holiday). As I'm newbie in this area, I'm a little confused.

If I use `RESOURCE_LOCAL`, I'll get "Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager." error. 

I've also tried to follow this [example](http://www.ryandelaplante.com/2009/08/how-to-use-glassfish-managed-jpa.html) that looks like a best aproach in my environment. Nothing helped :-(.